# How to Convert One Element List of Float String with Non-Uniform Spacing Between Them

Tags: python

I tried to convert string of float with uniform spacing between them, for example

```py
floating_num = ['6.7 6.8 6.9 7.0 7.1']
```

step 1: using `string` method `string.split()`

```
floating_num = floating_num[0].split(' ')
```

and got `list` of `string` `float` with 5 elements

```
floating_num = ['6.7', '6.8', '6.9', '7.0', '7.1']
```

step 2: then converted each element to `float` using list comprehension

```
floating_num = [float(x) for x in floating_num]
```

then got a `list` of `float` with 5 float type elements

```
floating_num = [6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1]
```

My Question:

I tried to convert `floating_num = ['6.7  6.8 6.9   7.0  7.1']` but with NON-HOMOGEN SPACING between each float string. For example spacing between 6.7 and 6.8 has 2 spaces, between 6.8 and 6.9 has 1 space, and between 6.9 has 3 spaces, etc. 
How to convert it to `list` of `float`?
I have tried it with step 1 and got this result

```
['6.7', '', '6.8', '6.9', '', '', '7.0', '', '7.1']
```

because separator i used in `split()` method only has 1 spacing `' '` so i got element with value `''`.
When I converted it to a float I got an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float.

Can string method `split()` apply to this? or there are some other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.split` with no argument handles multiple spaces.

```
x = '6.7  6.8 6.9   7.0  7.1'
[float(y) for y in x.split()]
# returns:
[6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
floating_num = ['6.7  6.8 6.9   7.0  7.1']
```

Option 1: Using regex to split

```
import re
temp = re.split('\s+', floating_num[0])
result = [float(x) for x in temp]
print(result)
#[6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1]
```

Option 2: without regex: only convert values to float that are non empty

```
temp = floating_num[0].split(' ')
result = [float(x) for x in temp if x]
print(result)
#[6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it:

```
>>> s = '6.7  6.8 6.9   7.0  7.1'
>>> [float(x) for x in s.split(" ") if x != ""]
[6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1]
```

Comment: In this approach, you can just use `[float(x) for x in s.split(" ") if x]`